# How do I configure AWS MFA for Gitlab Terraform Pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws, multi-factor-authentication

I would like to run a **GitLab pipeline** that manages **AWS** infrastructure via **Terraform**.

In order to Authenticate to AWS I need to use Multi Factor Authentication (**MFA**). But GitLab does not support any on demand authentication per pipeline run...

How should I proceed here?

I can only imagine that before a run of the pipeline, will MFA authenticate from the command line and set via **Gitlab API** the following pipeline variables with

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

and then I would run the pipeline.

I looked also into HC Vault, but I have not found any MFA solution. Only "more" secure pipeline variables.

I look forward for your suggestions.

Best regards,
Andrej

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to setup the gitlab pipeline but you might benefit from using terraform cloud, the pipeline works well out of the box and is free to use upto 5 or so users.

all you need to do is connect your infrastructure repo to you tfcloud organization, configure a deployment iam user , create your different workspaces for that organization, configure the input variables for workspaces(including aws creds) and then push code to the repo